# Unable to install Pillow in Python 3.8 virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

Unable to install Pillow 6.2.1 in Python 3.8 virtual environment.

Below is the error occurred during installation.

```
Command "C:\Users\rajksri2\Documents\venv\rs\Scripts\python.exe -u -c 

> Blockquote

"import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\rajksri2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-067_effw\\pillow\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rajksri2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ceg_4pcf\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\rajksri2\Documents\venv\rs\include\site\python3.8\pillow" 

failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rajksri2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-067_effw\pillow\
```

Comment: which pillow version are you trying to install?

Comment: Pillow 6.2.1@AdamStrauss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Pillow on Windows and Mac:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#windows-installation